# Open a .rtf file in a RichTextBox from a TreeView populated with .rtf files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, treeview

I have a TreeView populated with .rtf files and I want to load the files into a RichTextBox on click on a treenode.

Here is the code :

```
private string currentLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Notes";
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    string loc = currentLocation + "\\" + treeView1.SelectedNode.Text+ ".rtf";
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(loc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    richTextBox1.LoadFile(fs, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
}
```

And here is the error that occurs after I click a treenode :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What line is it throwing? Is the currentLocation null?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the function?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the node from the `e` parameter?  Use the IO.Path class to create those full file names.  Debug to see what the name is versus what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode tn=e.Node;
    string loc = currentLocation + "\\" + tn.Text+ ".rtf";
    richTextBox1.LoadFile(loc);
}
```

first you convert the selected(you cannot get the selected node from treeview) node to TreeNode, then with command tn.Text you get the text of the selected Node(the file name), after that you say to rich text box to load file from the path(you don't need to assign a file stream).

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain why this solves the problem?